# Websphere LibertyのSSL証明書の利用について

Tags: linux, docker, ssl

Websphere Liberty のDockerコンテナにおいて、コンテナ起動時デフォルトのSSL証明書が作成/ロードされてしまいます。
本来、使いたい証明書は自己証明書であり、server.xmlでデフォルト自己証明書を作成しない設定を入れているはずですが、なぜかデフォルト証明書がロードされてしまいます。

■server.xmlの内容

```
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>webProfile-8.0</feature>
        <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <!-- Define a default HTTP endpoint with SSL configuration -->
    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  sslRef="defaultSSLConfig"
                  httpPort="9080"
                  httpsPort="9443"
                  host="*">
        <sslOptions id="defaultSSLConfig"
                    keyStoreRef="MykeyStore"
                    sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"
                    sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
                    ciphers="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
                    clientAuthenticationSupported="false"
                    />
    </httpEndpoint>

    <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" autoCreate="false"/>

    <keyStore id="MykeyStore" location="/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/resources/security/key.jks" password="MyPassword"/>

    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files in the dropins folder -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

</server>
```

■dockerでの起動時ログ

```
# cat messages.log
********************************************************************************
product = WebSphere Application Server 18.0.0.3 (wlp-1.0.22.cl180320180905-2337)
wlp.install.dir = /opt/ibm/wlp/
server.output.dir = /opt/ibm/wlp/output/defaultServer/
java.home = /opt/ibm/java/jre
java.version = 1.8.0_201
java.runtime = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0.5.31 - pxa6480sr5fp31-20190311_03(SR5 FP31))
os = Linux (5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2; amd64) (ja_JP)
process = 1@595ad6aee684
********************************************************************************
[23/12/22 5:22:04:306 JST] 00000001 com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           A CWWKE0001I: サーバー defaultServer が起動されました。
[23/12/22 5:22:04:368 JST] 00000001 com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           A CWWKE0100I: この製品は、開発使用向け、および限定的な実動使用向けにライセンスが交付されています。 全ライセンス条項は以下で表示可能です: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/license/base_ilan/ilan/18.0.0.3/lafiles/ja.html
[23/12/22 5:22:07:979 JST] 0000002b com.ibm.ws.config.xml.internal.ServerXMLConfiguration        A CWWKG0093A: 構成ドロップイン・リソースを処理中です: /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/configDropins/defaults/keystore.xml
[23/12/22 5:22:09:118 JST] 00000001 com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           I CWWKE0002I: カーネルは 5.457 秒 秒後に始動されました。
[23/12/22 5:22:09:161 JST] 00000035 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            I CWWKF0007I: フィーチャー更新が開始しました。
[23/12/22 5:22:10:774 JST] 0000002b com.ibm.ws.security.ready.internal.SecurityReadyServiceImpl  I CWWKS0007I: セキュリティー・サービスを開始しています...
[23/12/22 5:22:11:124 JST] 0000002b com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.monitor.DropinMonitor        A CWWKZ0058I: アプリケーションの dropins をモニター中です。
[23/12/22 5:22:11:128 JST] 0000003c com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.TCPChannel                    I CWWKO0219I: TCP チャネル defaultHttpEndpoint が開始され、現在、ホスト *  (IPv4)、ポート 9080 の要求を listen しています。
[23/12/22 5:22:11:389 JST] 00000030 com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.WSKeyStore                             I CWPKI0802I: SSL 証明書を作成しています。 この処理には数秒かかる場合があります。
[23/12/22 5:22:11:398 JST] 00000042 com.ibm.ws.security.token.ltpa.internal.LTPAKeyInfoManager   I CWWKS4103I: LTPA 鍵を作成しています。 この処理には数秒かかる場合があります。
[23/12/22 5:22:11:423 JST] 0000002b ibm.ws.security.authentication.internal.jaas.JAASServiceImpl I CWWKS1123I: クラス名が NullCollectiveAuthenticationPlugin である集合認証プラグインがアクティブ化されました。 
[23/12/22 5:22:11:553 JST] 0000002b com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.AuthConfigFactoryWrapper           I CWWKS1655I: Java セキュリティー・プロパティー authconfigprovider.factory が設定されていないため、デフォルト Java Authentication SPI for Containers (JASPIC) AuthConfigFactory クラス com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.ProviderRegistry が使用されます。 
[23/12/22 5:22:12:024 JST] 00000042 com.ibm.ws.security.token.ltpa.internal.LTPAKeyInfoManager   A CWWKS4104A: LTPA 鍵が 0.626 秒で作成されました。 LTPA 鍵ファイル: /opt/ibm/wlp/output/defaultServer/resources/security/ltpa.keys
[23/12/22 5:22:12:029 JST] 00000042 com.ibm.ws.security.token.ltpa.internal.LTPAKeyCreateTask    I CWWKS4105I: LTPA 構成は、0.633 秒後に作動可能になります。
[23/12/22 5:22:12:477 JST] 0000002b com.ibm.ws.cache.ServerCache                                 I DYNA1001I: WebSphere 動的キャッシュ・インスタンス baseCache が正常に初期化されました。
[23/12/22 5:22:12:479 JST] 0000002b com.ibm.ws.cache.ServerCache                                 I DYNA1071I: キャッシュ・プロバイダー default が使用されています。
[23/12/22 5:22:12:480 JST] 0000002b com.ibm.ws.cache.CacheServiceImpl                            I DYNA1056I: 動的キャッシュ (オブジェクト・キャッシュ) が、正常に初期化されました。
[23/12/22 5:22:12:877 JST] 0000004c com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      I CWWKZ0018I: アプリケーション My-App を開始中です。
[23/12/22 5:22:12:877 JST] 0000004d com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      I CWWKZ0018I: アプリケーション My-App を開始中です。
[23/12/22 5:22:13:183 JST] 0000004d m.ibm.ws.container.service.app.deploy.ManifestClassPathUtils W SRVE9967W: マニフェスト・クラスパス pdq.jar が、JAR ファイル file:/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/expanded/My-App.war/WEB-INF/lib/jcc-11.1.4.4.jar またはその親に見つかりませんでした。
[23/12/22 5:22:13:183 JST] 0000004c m.ibm.ws.container.service.app.deploy.ManifestClassPathUtils W SRVE9967W: マニフェスト・クラスパス pdq.jar が、JAR ファイル file:/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/expanded/My-App.war/WEB-INF/lib/jcc-11.1.4.4.jar またはその親に見つかりませんでした。
[23/12/22 5:22:13:312 JST] 0000004c m.ibm.ws.container.service.app.deploy.ManifestClassPathUtils W SRVE9967W: マニフェスト・クラスパス pdq.jar が、JAR ファイル file:/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/expanded/My-App.war/WEB-INF/lib/jcc-11.1.4.4.jar またはその親に見つかりませんでした。
[23/12/22 5:22:13:503 JST] 0000004d m.ibm.ws.container.service.app.deploy.ManifestClassPathUtils W SRVE9967W: マニフェスト・クラスパス pdq.jar が、JAR ファイル file:/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/expanded/My-App.war/WEB-INF/lib/jcc-11.1.4.4.jar またはその親に見つかりませんでした。
[23/12/22 5:22:13:710 JST] 00000030 com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.WSKeyStore                             A CWPKI0803A: SSL 証明書の作成に 2.321 秒かかりました。 SSL 鍵ファイル: /opt/ibm/wlp/output/defaultServer/resources/security/key.jks
[23/12/22 5:22:13:780 JST] 0000003a com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.TCPChannel                    I CWWKO0219I: TCP チャネル defaultHttpEndpoint-ssl が開始され、現在、ホスト *  (IPv4)、ポート 9443 の要求を listen しています。
[23/12/22 5:22:13:784 JST] 0000003a com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.TCPChannel                    I CWWKO0220I: TCP チャネル defaultHttpEndpoint-ssl は、ホスト *  (IPv4)、ポート 9443 での要求の listen を停止しました。
[23/12/22 5:22:13:797 JST] 0000003a com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.TCPChannel                    I CWWKO0219I: TCP チャネル defaultHttpEndpoint-ssl が開始され、現在、ホスト *  (IPv4)、ポート 9443 の要求を listen しています。
[23/12/22 5:22:14:357 JST] 0000004d com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN8501I: セッション・マネージャーが、永続ストレージ・ロケーションを検出しませんでした。HttpSession オブジェクトはローカル・アプリケーション・サーバーのメモリーに保管されます。
[23/12/22 5:22:14:357 JST] 0000004c com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN8501I: セッション・マネージャーが、永続ストレージ・ロケーションを検出しませんでした。HttpSession オブジェクトはローカル・アプリケーション・サーバーのメモリーに保管されます。
[23/12/22 5:22:14:393 JST] 0000004c org.jboss.weld.Version                                       I WELD-000900: 3.0.5 (Final)
[23/12/22 5:22:15:740 JST] 0000004c org.jboss.weld.Event                                         I WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.CdiAnnotationProviderExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
[23/12/22 5:22:15:743 JST] 0000004d org.jboss.weld.Event                                         I WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.apache.myfaces.cdi.JsfArtifactProducerExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
[23/12/22 5:22:15:747 JST] 0000004d org.jboss.weld.Event                                         I WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.CdiAnnotationProviderExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
[23/12/22 5:22:15:754 JST] 0000004c org.jboss.weld.Event                                         I WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.apache.myfaces.cdi.JsfArtifactProducerExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
[23/12/22 5:22:15:809 JST] 0000004c org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version                I HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.12.Final
[23/12/22 5:22:16:442 JST] 0000004d com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Web モジュールをロード中: My-App。
[23/12/22 5:22:16:442 JST] 0000004c com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Web モジュールをロード中: My-App。
[23/12/22 5:22:16:445 JST] 0000004d com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web モジュール My-App は default_host にバインドされています。
[23/12/22 5:22:16:445 JST] 0000004c com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web モジュール My-App は default_host にバインドされています。
[23/12/22 5:22:16:446 JST] 0000004d com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web アプリケーションが使用可能です (default_host): http://595ad6aee684:9080/My-App/
[23/12/22 5:22:16:447 JST] 0000004c com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web アプリケーションが使用可能です (default_host): http://595ad6aee684:9080/My-App/
[23/12/22 5:22:16:451 JST] 0000004c com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      A CWWKZ0001I: アプリケーション My-App が 3.575 秒で開始しました。
[23/12/22 5:22:16:451 JST] 0000004d com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      A CWWKZ0001I: アプリケーション My-App が 3.575 秒で開始しました。
[23/12/22 5:22:16:475 JST] 00000069 com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0176I: アプリケーション・キー default_host/My-App に新しいセッション・コンテキストが作成されます。
[23/12/22 5:22:16:475 JST] 00000035 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0012I: サーバーは次のフィーチャーをインストールしました。[jsp-2.3, jsonb-1.0, ejbLite-3.2, managedBeans-1.0, beanValidation-2.0, servlet-4.0, jsf-2.3, ssl-1.0, jndi-1.0, cdi-2.0, jdbc-4.2, appSecurity-3.0, jsonp-1.1, appSecurity-2.0, jaxrsClient-2.1, el-3.0, jaxrs-2.1, jpaContainer-2.2, webProfile-8.0, jaspic-1.1, distributedMap-1.0, jpa-2.2, websocket-1.1]。
[23/12/22 5:22:16:475 JST] 00000058 com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0176I: アプリケーション・キー default_host/My-App に新しいセッション・コンテキストが作成されます。
[23/12/22 5:22:16:475 JST] 00000035 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            I CWWKF0008I: フィーチャー更新が 7.357 秒で完了しました。
[23/12/22 5:22:16:476 JST] 00000035 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0011I: サーバー defaultServer は、Smarter Planet に対応する準備ができました。
[23/12/22 5:22:16:494 JST] 00000069 com.ibm.ws.util                                              I SESN0172I: セッション・マネージャーは、セッション ID の生成に Java のデフォルト SecureRandom 実装を使用しています。
[23/12/22 5:22:16:505 JST] 00000058 com.ibm.ws.util                                              I SESN0172I: セッション・マネージャーは、セッション ID の生成に Java のデフォルト SecureRandom 実装を使用しています。
[23/12/22 5:22:16:562 JST] 00000037 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.mbeans.PluginGenerator          I SRVE9103I: Web サーバー・プラグイン構成ファイルは、このサーバー用に、/opt/ibm/wlp/output/defaultServer/logs/state/plugin-cfg.xml に自動的に生成されました。
[23/12/22 5:22:16:597 JST] 00000069 com.ibm.ws.cache.CacheServiceImpl                            I DYNA1056I: 動的キャッシュ (オブジェクト・キャッシュ) が、正常に初期化されました。
[23/12/22 5:22:16:613 JST] 00000069 org.apache.myfaces.ee.MyFacesContainerInitializer            I Using org.apache.myfaces.ee.MyFacesContainerInitializer
[23/12/22 5:22:16:613 JST] 00000058 org.apache.myfaces.ee.MyFacesContainerInitializer            I Using org.apache.myfaces.ee.MyFacesContainerInitializer
#
```

実現したいこととしては、デフォルトの証明書を利用してしまうと、CN=localhostとなってしまい証明書エラーが発生するので、/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/resources/security/key.jksにある自己証明書を利用したいですが、方法がわかりません。

ご教授よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

こちら自己解決をしました。
参考になるかわかりませんが、解決方法を載せておきます。

まず、Websphere Libertyは開発者の環境構築を容易にするため、デフォルトで「/opt/ibm/wlp/output/defaultServer/resources/security/」配下にkey.jksファイルが作成されるそうです。

そして、デフォルトでは、SSL証明書の参照先は作成されたkey.jksファイルを参照するように設定されている？ので、CN=localhostとなっていました。

そこで、デフォルトの証明書をそもそも無理やりですが上書きすればよいのではないかと考え、Dockerfile内で、事前に作成されたkey.jksファイルを「/opt/ibm/wlp/output/defaultServer/resources/security/」にコピーすることで、デフォルトで作成されたkey.jksではなく事前に作成した証明書を利用することができました。

ただし、デフォルトのkey.jksファイルのパスワードは「/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/configDropins/defaults/keystore.xml」に配置されているので、単にDockerfileでコピーコマンドを実行しただけではパスワードエラーが起きるので、keystore.xmlも事前に作成し、上書きすることでパスワードエラーを回避できます。

これが正しい解決方法かはわかりませんが、一応回答として記載します。

※補足
Dockerfile内でのコピーコマンド

```
COPY ./keystore.xml /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/configDropins/defaults/keystore.xml

COPY ./key.jks /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/resources/security/key.jks
COPY ./key.jks /opt/ibm/wlp/output/defaultServer/resources/security/key.jks
```